# Elementary proof that a binomial distribution with $p\ne \frac12$ is almost symmetric?

Tags: probability

I am looking for an elementary explanation of why a loaded coin gets more and less than the expected number of heads approximately equiprobably, in other words, *mean*=*median*.

Mathematically speaking, if $X\sim B(n,p)$ is a [Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) random variable, then $P(X<np)\approx P(X>np)$ for large $n$.

When $p=\frac12$, this is obvious because of the exact symmetry of the distribution around $\frac{n}{2}$.

For a general $0<p<1$ this follows from [convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) of $X$ to the [Gaussian Normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) distribution.

Is there an elementary intuitive explanation?

Comment: interesting question.  for a general r.v. $X$, the mean and the median are not necessarily the same, i.e. $P(X > E[X]) \neq P(X < E[X])$.  i suspect we do have to pull in the CLT to explain why mean = median for $X = B(n,p)$.  but i would love to see an alternate "elementary intuitive" explanation.